# Apache Basic Auth only for Requests with URL Path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, basic-authentication

I'd like to get Basic Authentication for everything except requests from a certain IP Range and URLs that have a URL Path. (In my scenario these always end with .html)

The IP Range works fine, but I can't get requests to go threw that end with .html. For example:

> http://subdomain.domain.com/test.html or http://subdomain.domain.com/test/test.html

should be allowed without authentication, while

> http://subdomain.domain.com or http://domain.com

should be denied.

This is the Basic Auth block in my .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".html$" auth=1

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthName "Login"
require valid-user
Allow from 123.456.78 env=auth
Satisfy Any
```

Answer (score 2):

You need 2 different `Allow` lines:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.html$" NO_AUTH

AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthName "Login"
require valid-user
Satisfy Any

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 123.456.78
Allow from env=NO_AUTH
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still asks me to authenticate for URLs with an ending .html

Comment: You've some other config issue as I have tested same code on my Apache with and without `Allow from 123.456.78` line and it works fine both ways.